# How to only use a certain dict from a get request with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have exposed to Backbone an API that returns user profiles with this structure:
{id: 1, following: {...}}. I only want to use the dictionary inside of the "following" attribute. How would I do that? Right now, I have a model with a URL to the API. I have a collection that uses this model. I do a fetch() on the collection, but I only want to use the dictionary inside of "following".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`parse`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) to extract what you want from the the response:

> **parse** `model.parse(response)`
>
> **parse** is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in `fetch`, and `save`. The function is passed the raw `response` object, and should return the attributes hash to be set on the model.

So you'd want something like this in your model:

```
parse: function(response) {
    return response.following;
}
```